# Keep element of formula as it is

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, evaluation, symbolic

I have

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
de = f''[y] - (n^2 \[Pi]^2)/(4 a^2) f[y];
DSolve[de == -q/S (4/(n \[Pi] b))(-1)^((n - 1)/2), f[y], y]
```

and I would like the $(-1)^{(n - 1)/2}$ to be kept as it is in the solution, without using $i$. I remember that there is a way to do this but I forgot what the command is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
de = f''[y] - (n^2 π^2)/(4 a^2) f[y];
DSolve[de == -q/S (4/(n π b)) (-1)^((n - 1)/2), f[y], y] /. 
 Times[Complex[0, -16], Power[Complex[0, 1], n_], a__] -> (HoldForm[-1])^((n + 1)/2)*a
```

[image]

As soon as you want to remove the `HoldForm`, apply `ReleaseHold` to the expression.

Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

One way might be

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
de = f''[y] - (n^2 Pi^2)/(4 a^2) f[y];
myTerm = HoldForm[(-1)^((n - 1)/2)];
DSolve[de == -q/S (4/(n Pi b)) myTerm, f[y], y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You'd have to release the hold to use the answer though

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. What do you mean that I would have to release the hold to use the answer?

Comment: @enea19 I mean later on, if you want to use the solution for anything that require evaluations, such as plotting or getting numerical values or any other type of computation using the solution, you need to release the Hold on that term so that Mathematica can evaluate it.

Comment: Otherwise Mathematica will keep it as $(−1)^{(n−1)/2}$ forever? It's not necessarily a bad thing for the derivation that I have to do since I don't want $i$s but thanks for the warning.

Comment: You could use Defer instead of HoldForm